# Add ChildItem to TreeView's SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, selecteditem

I have a `TreeView` in my WPF application. The user can create categories in this `TreeView`. Now I want to add an Item to the selected item of the `Treeview`. How do I add a `childItem` to the selected item in a `Treeiew`?

The following code doesn't work, how can I go about fixing this?

The current code I have:

```
if (treeViewCategories.SelectedItem != null)
{
    //Unable to cast the SelectedItem to a TreeViewItem('System.String' to 'System.Windows.constrol.TreeViewItem)
    TreeViewItem selectedItem = (TreeViewItem)treeViewCategories.SelectedItem;
    selectedItem.Items.Add(pictureList[counter]);
}
```

Comment: Might help avoid those downvotes if you provide a little more information, are you using mvvm for a start? Show us a little code for the point where you want to add this child entry.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Is [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=add+item+to+selected+treeview+c%23&oq=add+item+to+selected+treeview+c%23&aqs=chrome..69i57.4868j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) down? *COUGH* [2nd result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984278(v=vs.71).aspx) *COUGH*

Comment: @tnw the links you gave is for a Windows Forms Application. My tag states WPF. The TreeView.SelectedItem.Items.Add. Isn't available in wpf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TreeView` in WPF has a property called [`SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.selecteditem.aspx).

```
TreeViewItem selectedTVI = (TreeViewItem)myTreeView.SelectedItem;
selectedTVI.Items.Add(newChild);
```

You should [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.selectedvalue.aspx). `SelectedValue` is the "**value** of the property that is the specified by SelectedValuePath for the SelectedItem", not the actual `SelectedItem` which I've shown above.

Comment: Problem with this is I get the "Unable to cast object of Type ' System.String' to 'System.Windows.Controls.TreeiewItem'. That's why I started experimenting with the above code with no result.

Comment: @daJbot OK, the error message is pretty straight forward. You should read it again. You're passing `Add` a `string` and not a `TreeViewItem`. There's no problem with the code I showed here. You even had it right earlier: `TreeViewItem newChild = new TreeViewItem(); newChild.Header = pictureList[counter];` use that and *then* add `newChild`

Comment: Still have the same error after changing the code to what you suggested. Seems the error is when I try to cast the SelectedItem to a TreeViewItem (first line of your code). Not sure why because it should work as the SelectedItem is a TreeViewItem.

Comment: That moment when you want to give your self a mega FacePalm. I messed up when adding the new Category. There I added a string rather then a TreeViewItem. My apologies, and thanks for the help here!

Comment: @daJbot Post exactly what you have, that makes absolutely no sense. EDIT: Good to hear, glad to help.